# Can Mercury's orbit be explained without relativity?

Tags: planets, physics, astrophysics

The orbit of mercury is different than rest of the planets. The reason for this seemed unaccounted for in Newtonian physics, and was later explained by Einstein's theory of relativity.

[Here is a quick video that explains this easily.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSXNE0pNtr8)

For a while astronomers looked for a different planet/asteroid field structure to compensate for this, and therefore make it fit into the Newtonian physics prediction. My question is: what if they should have been looking inside the sun for this change in gravity?

If the sun had a center of density that wobbled in a certain way, could this result in the observable Mercury orbit?

I am not that interested in what ramifications are caused by challenging relativity, if I want to be called a heretic I will post this on the physics page. :)

Simply put, could the discrepancy between Newton's prediction and real world measurements of Mercury's orbit be a result of variations in the center of density of the Sun?

Comment: No, it won't work; or, better said, it won't work without affecting the orbits of the other planets. The problem with the abnormal [perihelion precession of Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity#Perihelion_precession_of_Mercury) is that it is a phenomenon observed for *Mercury* and not for Venus, for example.

Comment: World Building isn't a good place for this question, and as the video explains, they were already looking for a planet, Vulcan. -- For science questions, World Building is for "If I change X, then what would Y, Z, and A look like?" Not for "If X is changed, what does X look like?" ... because we already know what X looks like, you just described it to us.  We're here assuming that you're an artist (writer, game dev., etc.) establishing a setting, finding out what others see as reasonable, and when to use handwavium/unobtanium... not a curious non-artist satisfying an itch.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a straight physics (or astronomy) question and there are SE sites for that.

Comment: @StephenG, [The moderators ruled that real-world questions, even if they have "more appropriate" SE sites, are on-topic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/a-proposal-to-finalize-the-are-real-world-questions-on-topic-debate).  And the very suggestion that the Mercurian orbit may be due to variations with the sun is fundamentally a worldbuilding context.

Comment: @AlexP, let me throw an idea at you.  Let's say that there was a bubble of high-density-something in the sun itself that, as the sun rotates, would cause a slight perterbation in the spacetime fabric near Mercury.  Considering the overall gravitational strength, such a small perturbation wouldn't affect the more distant planets, would it?  It's actually an intriguing idea.  [Think this...](http://sunorbit.net/S3-13b_anno.jpg)

Comment: If a planet's orbit were unaffected by other planets (perfect orbit in other words), then Newtonian physics could accurately predict its path.  With other planets, it would steadily go off course until it were completely off base.

Comment: I concur with StephenG: while there are real-world queries that fit WB.SE, this really isn't one of them. As asked, there is no worldbuilding context or rationale for this question to be asked here. It's just one of those randomly interesting but off-topic questions I see here every day.

Comment: my thoughts exactly @JBH

Comment: @elemtilas, I understand, but the point I made for my part in the real-world question debate was that there's no practical difference between a real-world question with or without a WB context.  If the only difference is some statement reading, "Oh, and I'm doing this for my fictional world Xebieus," then there's really no point to mandating a WB context.  Worse, most of our sister sites don't/won't entertain fictional questions like this, leaving the OP nowhere to go.  Thus (among other things) the reason for making real-world questions on-topic.

Comment: @JBH - Yep, the never-ending debate! I'm sorry you feel they have nowhere to go (not actually true, SE is not the only Q&A forum available), but really, this isn't "PANFICTION.SE" either! We're here for *constructing imaginary worlds and settings*.  It's just my opinion, but let the community decide which off-topic questions it will tolerate and which it will eliminate.

Comment: @elemtilas, yeah... that's fair.

Answer (score 4):

Historically, there were several alternative explanations of Mercury's orbit before general relativity came in.

The most popular hypothesis was the assumption of an additional inner planet (it was even named [Vulcan or Zoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_(hypothetical_planet))) that was almost impossible to see (essentially, it is only visible during a solar eclipse or during a transit).

Another possible assumption is a shape of the sun that diverges significantly from a sphere, a quadrupole moment of Newtonian gravitation can explain Mercury's orbit.

General relativity is the accepted reason because besides the orbit of Mercury it predicted other effects like bending the course of a ray of light passing the sun closely.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably plenty of ways to get there from adding *additional* physics. Specifically ruling out relativity is probably extremely doable. That said, if you want to ignore other observed phenomena and focus on just this orbit *without* adding anything else... then possibly?

Since this isn't [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science) I'm going to throw a thought experiment at you.

If you imagined a redistribution of mass in or near the Sun to account for this orbit then you have the same question about this mass distribution:

"How did you get it with Newtonian physics acting *on itself*?"

Which you could *maybe* answer by saying there was some *coupling* on it of a similar nature. Which *maybe* Mercury or the new mass itself provides. If you're providing a closed loop of effects at some point then you're positing a "stable" system in a now *extremely* sensitive and chaotic environment; since it's an orbit not predicated on a single giant mass with negligible outside interference, but a "chain" of masses in concert. Granted it's less chaotic without things like gravity waves, etc. but I would... *assume* that orbits would decay faster than they already do for such a precisely orchestrated setup. Unless there was some self-reinforcing factor for this distribution of energy and mass.... which, under Newtonian physics, I don't recall there being any mechanism to achieve this in space. Stability under precise conditions maybe, self-reinforcing stability I don't recall though. Maybe balancing pressures (light, etc.)?

**Conclusion,** don't necessarily know enough off-hand and didn't do the research. But it seems like ***possibly*** with a decent dose of ***"I am suspending my disbelief for you".*** (Especially since any world building where mentioning this as a factor in-universe is going to have them thinking about ramifications of non-relativity anyway... ie *readers are smart too*)

Comment: The "chain" part is the most relevant piece of the thought experiment. The rest is gap and tangent filler. :3

Comment: Most mass "chains" (moons, etc.) don't form closed feedback loops. Asteroid belt you could argue, but the entire mass of the belt is actually exceedingly small. To the point where it's basically non-existent. (I believe it also on rare occasion kicks asteroids? Which would be catastrophic on a "single body" orbit like Mercury)

Comment: well in my ignorant head, i was envisioning something contained within the Sun. Perhaps a shifting mass of matter (liquid mass churning)... or a cycle of matter getting dense then erupting etc. Obviously our capability of understanding the internal workings of the SUN are....limited lol

Comment: Yeah that's how I would do too. You can get a bit hand-wavey with things nobody ever has a chance of seeing in a million years (but maybe not 2 million! :P). If the in-universe gets too close to the question you can have them just say "I don't know". Not ideal of course, which I assume is one of the things the Q is meant to handle.